# Extract zip file in S3 Bucket using AWS lambda functions in nodeJs "Error: Invalid CEN header (bad signature)"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am struggling with unzipping the contents in AWS S3. AWS S3 does not provide the functionality of unzipping the zip folder in the S3 bucket directly. I facing one error . upload code screenshot attached.[image]
[image]"Error: Invalid CEN header (bad signature)"

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

My node Js code to upload the zip file:

```
 const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
 const s3 = new AWS.S3({signatureVersion: 'v4'});
 exports.handler = async (event,context) => {
 const bucket = 'bucket-name';
 console.log(event)
 const body = event.body;
 const key=JSON.parse(body).key
 console.log(key)
 const params = {
 Bucket: bucket,
 Key: key,
 ContentType: 'application/zip',
 Expires: 60
};
try{
const signedURL = await s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params);
const response = {
    err:{},
    body:"url send",
    url:signedURL
  };
  return response;
 }catch(e){
    const response = {
    err:e.message,
    body:"error occured"
   };
  return response;
  }};
```

My NodeJs code to extract the zip file:

```
const S3Unzip = require('s3-unzip'); 

exports.s3_unzip = function(event, context, callback) { 
const filename = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
const bucketname = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
console.log(event.Records[0].s3.object.key);

new S3Unzip({ 
    bucket: bucketname, 
    file: filename,
    deleteOnSuccess: true,
    verbose: true, 
}, function(err, success) { 
    if (err) { 
        callback(err); 
    } else { 
        callback(null); 
    } 
});
}
```

Comment: Are you executing this on AWS Lambda? Also, check that the MIME type of your zip archive is correct (should be `application/zip`), the library you're using says it works only when that's set correctly. I just tried to upload a zip file on a bucket and ran your code locally and it works just fine.

Comment: yes, I am using AWS lambda function and also check it's working fine while I upload zip file manually. but form code it's thorw error

Comment: basically the metadata of the file is set to System defined key as  Content-Type and value is multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------140614706817724029235152, but when I set in code as Param metadata then it's set as user defined and key is "x-amz-meta-" but still my lambda trigger throws error

Comment: yes issue is fixed now.Thanks @Andre.IDK for valuable input to debug further..!! The mistake was in upload by postman I have used binary  instead of form-data

Comment: How did you fix this issue?